# Formula for counting the number of blanks in one column,filtered, and counting the number of times a specific number appears in that filter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to display how many times a specific "Station" has a blank in its column. I have it set up to where the column that has all the blanks filters to where it only shows the blanks, and the other column only displays the specific stations that have blanks in the first column.

I have tried countless `COUNTIF` statements, but nothing seems to be working. here is an example of what have so far `=COUNTIFS(Comments!C:C,"11")` This counts the number of time Station 11 pops up without the filter added. I don't know how to use the filter in order to count the number of times station 11 comes up and has a blank in the comment column

`=COUNTIFS(Comments!A:A,"",Comments!C:C,"11")` ???? this doesn't seem to work though nor does it add the filter that I have on it.

I expect the outcome to give me the total number of "Blanks" in Station 11.

Comment: Add some sample data or a screenshot. Can't replicate based on what you have so far.

Comment: Agreed with @BigBen that we need to see your data to actually help. But in general, if you want to perform an operation on filtered data, you need to use the [`SUBTOTAL` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939). `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` look at all the data (even if it is invisible due to being filtered out or if cells are manually hidden).

Comment: Your formula works fine for me.

Comment: Are your 'Blanks' really blank? Is this data imported? Quite often there are trailing spaces or other unseen characters in these columns troubling a rather straightforward function.

Answer (score 0):

To count a blanks station and 11 u can use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Comments!C:C;"Station 11")+(COUNTIFS(Comments!C:C;"11")
```

u can add all the ways you want just add a one more condittion
If you want blanks u use

```
=COUNTIFS(Comments!C:C;"")
```